# Blink doesn't work on pin D3,D4 and D0 but works on D7

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am facing a strange issue. I am trying to blink an external LED using **Wemos D1 mini V2 board**. But it is not working. My sketch is as below.

```
int LED = D3;
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT); 
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);   // LED off
  delay(1000);              // Wait 1 second
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);  // LED on
  delay(1000);              // Wait 1 second
}
```

The same problem happens on D0, D3, and D4 pins. I am getting 0 volts constantly on pin D0 and 3.3v constantly on pins D3 and D4.

However, The same sketch works for the D7 pin.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This code should just work. If you're setting LED to D4 it should blink the internal LED. What happens if you do that? How are you measuring the voltage? Also, please make a habit of properly indenting your code, even with such a small program.

Comment: Make sure all your SW and FW is up to date.  Trying to get so many different processor to work like the original Atmel processor on the original Arduino UNO is no easy task.  Even the well known Adafruit.com got the this wrong in the beginning.